# Удаление дубликатов в массиве через рекурсию в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, поиск

столкнулся с интересной ситуацией:

- есть некий массив `$arr= ['зеленый','коричневый','синий','коричневый','красный','синий','черный','фиолетовый','коричневый','синий']`,
  в котором необходимо удалить некий элементы и его возможные дубликаты по значению, к примеру 'синий'.
- есть функция:

```
function del_by_value($arr, $del_value){   
    
    if (($key = array_search($del_value, $arr)) !== FALSE) { //единично находим интересующий элемент возвращает его в переменную.
        
        unset($arr[$key]);// удаляем его

        del_by_value($arr, $del_value); // рекурсивно вызываем функцию для проверки массива, и возможного удаления дубликатов 
           
        }
     return $arr;// если элемент (значение) не найден, то возвращаем массив.
   
}

$arr = del_by_value($arr, 'синий');
```

По логике, функция должна пройти по всем элементам и вернуть массив без дубликатов, на практике возвращается:

```
array(9) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "зеленый"
  [1] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [3] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [4] =>
  string(14) "красный"
  [5] =>
  string(10) "синий"
  [6] =>
  string(12) "черный"
  [7] =>
  string(20) "фиолетовый"
  [8] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [9] =>
  string(10) "синий"
}
```

T.e. удален только первый элемент. Рекурсия работает и, если проверять на разных участках кода, то массив с удаленным элементами появляется на 3-ей итерации:

```
unset($arr[$key]);// удаляем его
 var_dump($arr);

array(7) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "зеленый"
  [1] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [3] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [4] =>
  string(14) "красный"
  [6] =>
  string(12) "черный"
  [7] =>
  string(20) "фиолетовый"
  [8] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
}
```

Однако функция возвращает не этот результат. Предполагаю, что нужно копать в вопрос с памятью php, он как-то логично для себя заносит результаты работы с $arr в другой последовательности и возвращает только первую итерацию?

Comment: ваша рекурсивная функция возвращает собственно массив измененный. Но выже не перезаписываете его а-ля `$arr = func(...)`, аот и получаете на выходе, что удален  только первый

Comment: и надеюсь, вы просто упражняетесь  с рекурсиями, ибо это задача для `array_filter` с сохранением флага первого соответствия во внешнюю переменную, а не для рекурсий

Comment: Да, упражняюсь. Здесь не отметил, но переменную перезаписывал, результат прежний, именно с него и получал :   array(9) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "зеленый"
  [1] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [3] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [4] =>
  string(14) "красный"
  [5] =>
  string(10) "синий"
  [6] =>
  string(12) "черный"
  [7] =>
  string(20) "фиолетовый"
  [8] =>
  string(20) "коричневый"
  [9] =>
  string(10) "синий"
} скорректировал код, чтобы не возникало по этому моменту вопросов. :)

Comment: teran, все я понял свою ошибку, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил на полную прогу

```
$arr = ['зеленый','коричневый','синий','коричневый','красный','синий','черный','фиолетовый','коричневый','синий'];

function del_by_value($arr, $del_value){   
    
    if (($key = array_search($del_value, $arr)) !== FALSE) { //единично находим интересующий элемент возвращает его в переменную.
        
        unset($arr[$key]);// удаляем его

        $arr = del_by_value($arr, $del_value); // рекурсивно вызываем функцию для проверки массива, и возможного удаления дубликатов 
           
        }
     return $arr;// если элемент (значение) не найден, то возвращаем массив.
   
}

$n = del_by_value($arr, 'синий');

var_dump($n);
```

Вывод на экран:

```
array(7) {
[0] =>
string(14) "зеленый"
[1] =>
string(20) "коричневый"
[3] =>
string(20) "коричневый"
[4] =>
string(14) "красный"
[6] =>
string(12) "черный"
[7] =>
string(20) "фиолетовый"
[8] =>
string(20) "коричневый"
}
```

Comment: для иправлений есть кнопка Править под вопросом

Comment: У меня её нет (ещё наверное)

Comment: аа. пардоньте, я что-то подумал что это автор вопроса дополнение написал.

Comment: Увы, но это так не работает. :) Если есть возможность, прогоните в своих IDE этот код, может у меня что-то VSC не так...

Comment: @Денис - эту прогу (я всю положил) я запустил просто через php ИмяПрограммы.php. Похоже Вы забыли получить новый массив из  $n = del_by_value($arr, 'синий');

Comment: @Виктор, видимо у меня что-о с IDE... впервые с таким сталкиваюсь. Новую переменную я объявлял, для получения массива, сюда перенес не полностью скопированное обращение (уже исправил), но мой VSC  выдает не тот результат, который  получаете вы. Но самое главное для меня, что логика работает правильно. :) Спасибо!

Comment: @Виктор, все я все понял. Спасибо! :))))

Comment: Помечайте как ответ и жмите стрелочку вверх :)

Comment: @Виктор, все сделал. :) Еще раз благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

@Виктор и @teran помогли мне разобраться в моем вопросе, я забыл перезаписать переменную $arr на втором вызове функции, но если вдруг кому - то в качествен изучения рекурсии и практики будет интересно, то думаю стоит оставить данную реализацию поиска для изучения.

Рабочая реализация алгоритма приведена @Виктор выше.